# Embed PDFs in dynamic HTML (Angular 4)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pdf, embed

I need to make a html-string, which contains some PDFs from my database.

I tried `<embed src='URL.createObjectUrl(someBlob)' ...>`.Iframe- and object-tag aren't working, too. I don't really know any other method. Maybe there is a way to display them as picture, so that i don't need to use the ObjectUrl.

I also can't save dem to a filesystem. Otherwise, this wouldn't be so difficult.

**WORKAROUND**

It is just impossible to do that how i wanted to. if someone tells me the opposite, i want to know that please.

I solved it with sending the id's of the pdfs which i need to my Webservice. This service calls another of my webservices to get all the needed byte-Arrays from a database. In the first service, I use iText, a library, to concat these blobs to one. Now I can pass this big array of bytes to my frontend.

It is a bit much passing and parsing around through my apis and libraries, but it works fine until this point.

Comment: No, because they all get their data from a Filesystem

Comment: Ah, I see, missed that part. Maybe you can put some more accent on it ;-)

Comment: You didn't miss that. I edited it, because so itself did ask me, if this post is a duplicate :D

Comment: *I solved it with sending the id's of the pdfs which i need to my Webservice. This service calls another of my webservices to get all the needed byte-Arrays from a database. In the first service, I use iText, a library, to concat these blobs to one. Now I can pass this big array of bytes to my frontend.* It seems to me that this can also be done with one service.